# Five star rating sysytem for cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

PLease tell me how to implement fivestar rating system in cakephp 2.0?

Comment: I know this is largely useless but... [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I dint find the method to implement this rating system , im totally unknown to this.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a plugin to show star rating. Here is [Star Rating Plugin for cakephp](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/schneimi/2010/08/19/ajax-star-rating-plugin-1). I used it and it is working fine.
Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Absolutely, I used it and it worked well even with CakePHP 2.1, however it needed some customization while working with CakePHP 2.1+